# Simulate :first-child selector in CSS

Tags: css

Tell me please if exists any method to simulate :first-child selector in `CSS`, I need the same functionality but without :first-child

Comment: its like, `color: red;` but without `color`, how to do this? i think you will need JavaScript to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:nth-child(1)` can be a alternative

but this is a CSS3 selector, your browser must support css3